# How to change [filter: blur] value with scrollTop()?

Tags: jquery, filter, scroll, blur, scrolltop

I saw the codepen for the Medium scroll effect, but it isn't exactly what I'm looking for because it doesn't properly blur images -- it only changes the opacity.

So I have a div:

```
img.blur {
width: 100vw;
min-width: 800px;
filter: blur(20px);
}
```

How can I use the jQuery scrollTop() function to configure it so that as I scroll down the page the filter: blur will decrease or increase?

The one from codepen is:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    opacityVal = (s / 150.0);
    $('.blurred-img').css('opacity', opacityVal);
});
```

So I figured I'd change the affected CSS div to `$('img.blur')` but I have no idea what to change `opacity` and `opacityVal` to.

Thanks!

---

EDIT: I want something like this effect here:

http://jsfiddle.net/byrichardpowell/38MGS/1/

Except when I scroll.

I basically want to do something similar to what they do on the first part of FFMark.com.

Comment: make JSFiddle for more understanding

Answer (score 0):

you just have to set a 100% height on which your complete blurred image will be shown

```
var MAXSCROLLHEIGHT = 150; // on MAXSCROLLHEIGHT pixel scroll height, the blurred image will be shown on 100% opacity
$(window).scroll(function() {
    opacityVal = $(window).scrollTop() / MAXSCROLLHEIGHT; // replaced the fix value by possible config variable
    if(opacityVal > 1) return; // won't affect the image as you keep scrolling
    $('img.blur').css('opacity', opacityVal);
});
```

i think with the check of opacityVal you'll improve performance a bit because you wont affect the element as you keep scrolling beyond your MAXSCROLLHEIGHT

Comment: That's not the problem. I've already gotten opacityVal to work. I don't want to reduce the opacity on scroll, I want to change the filter:blur radius on scroll.